# Exception has occured OSError for Python Tkinter background image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-unicode, photoimage

I am trying to use a picture as my background in my Tkinter window but every time I try to load the image it keeps giving me this error:

```
 Invalid argument: ':\\Users\\name\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\coins.png'
```

Before that I was getting a Unicode error `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape`
so I used this  `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

I also tried putting an r before my normal string, doubling the forward slashes (ex. \ to \\ ), and changing my forward slashes to backward slashes. I know I need a raw string for this to work but out of ideas on how to solve it.

I would appreciate any help you guys can give me!

Here is my code:

```
image = Image.open(r":\Users\name\OneDrive\Pictures\coins.png")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
root.background_label = tk.Label(image=photo)
root.background_label.image = photo
root.background_label.place(x=0,y=0)
```

Comment: You just forgot to print in the dirve like `r"C:\Users\name\OneDrive\Pictures\coins.png"`

Comment: @Atlas435 What do you mean by print in the drive? Sorry, I'm not understanding.

Comment: Your path isnt completed yet, you need to put in the drive.

Comment: @Atlas435 Sorry I just did that and now I have this error:                                              
No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\name\\OneDrive\\Pictures\\coins.png

Comment: Well then it seems pretty much that your path is incorrect. Are your sure the path is correct? which os are you running?

Comment: @Atlas435 I have a windows 10 and I just doubled checked my path and it was wrong so I changed it but now I'm getting this error PermissionError [Errno13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\name\\Pictures'

Comment: add in your code `import os` and add `print(os.access(*filepath*, os.R_OK))` before open it with PIL and let me know what it is printing.

Comment: @Atlas435 It printed True in the terminal then I got the same PermissioError.

Comment: @Atlas435 I figured it out already thank you!

Comment: glad to hear that